# ReadBlockFromDisk: Errors in block header at CBlockDiskPos

Tags: bitcoin, litecoin

So at litecoin newest source, after I set all values as mine, first run ./xxxcoind , nothing happen, it seems stop, so I opened debug.log file, it says

> 2018-02-21 11:44:37 ERROR: AcceptBlock: high-hash, proof of work
>   failed (code 16)
>
> 2018-02-21 11:44:37 Reindexing finished
>
> 2018-02-21 11:44:37 Failed to open mempool file from disk. Continuing
>   anyway.
>
> 2018-02-21 11:48:22 Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra
>   outbound peer (last tip update: 180 seconds ago)
>
> 2018-02-21 11:51:22 Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra
>   outbound peer (last tip update: 360 seconds ago)

So I searched about [Potential stale....] some says add [ -connect=0 ], so I did, then again past same error appears...

> 2018-02-21 12:47:18 ERROR: ReadBlockFromDisk: Errors in block header
>   at CBlockDiskPos(nFile=0, nPos=8)
>
> 2018-02-21 12:47:18 *** Failed to read block
>
> 2018-02-21 12:47:18 Error: Error: A fatal internal error occurred, see
>   debug.log for details

Why and how to resolve... ? 
This seems same error before I set GenesisHash and merkleroot as mine. 
Very frustrating to see again this error..

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

you can change genesis params in `src/chainparam.cpp`  adjust nonce value (like +1, +2 ..) until match beneath target